# How to scrape wikipedia text from <p> without id or class?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, wikipedia

I am scraping a Wikipedia text but the `<p>` does not have any class or id:

```
import requests as r
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url=r.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia#Nupedia")
soup=bs(url.text,'html.parser')
print(soup)

product=soup.find('div',class_="mw-parser-output")
head=product.find('span',id="Nupedia").text
para=product.find_all('p',class_=False)
print(para)
```

It's not working

[image: 1]

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: do you want all <p> tags that don't have a class?  Or is there a specific one, if so then what is unique about it?

Comment: i want heading =Nupedia and the paragraph of it's below then another heading and so on but i only can get heading i am unable to get the paragraph of it as it dosen't have any class or id

Answer (score 1):

Question is not quiet clear - To get only the next `<p>` you could go with:

```
product.find('span',id="Nupedia").find_next('p').text
```

If you like to extract the headlines and its corresponding `<p>`s you can go with something like that:

```
for h in soup.select('h3'):
    print(h.text)
    for t in h.next_siblings:
        if t.name == 'h3':
            break
        if t.name == 'p':
            print(t.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get text from p tag, you can use `.find_next_sibling('p')`

```
import requests as r
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
url=r.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia#Nupedia")
soup=bs(url.text,'html.parser')
#print(soup)
product=soup.find('div',class_="mw-parser-output")
head=product.find('span',id="Nupedia")
para=product.find('div',class_="thumb tright").find_next_sibling('p').get_text(strip=True)
print(para)
```

**Output:**

```
Other collaborative online encyclopedias were attempted before Wikipedia, but none were as successful.[17]Wikipedia began as a complementary project forNupedia, a free online English-language encyclopedia project whose articles were written by experts and reviewed under a formal process.[18]It was founded on March 9, 2000, under the ownership ofBomis, aweb portalcompany. Its main figures were Bomis CEOJimmy WalesandLarry Sanger,editor-in-chieffor Nupedia and later Wikipedia.[1][19]Nupedia was initially licensed under its own NupediaOpen ContentLicense, but even before Wikipedia was founded, Nupedia switched to theGNU Free Documentation Licenseat the 
urging ofRichard Stallman.[20]Wales is credited with defining the goal of making a publicly editable encyclopedia,[21][22]while Sanger is credited with the strategy of using awikito reach 
that goal.[23]On January 10, 2001, Sanger proposed on the Nupedia mailing list to create a wiki as a "feeder" project for Nupedia.[24]
```